# Creating a displacement texture for 3D printing using geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, displacement, geometry-nodes, distort

Creating a displacement texture for 3D printing using geometry nodes

I'm trying to recreate a pattern within a shape and include a displacement in geometry nodes so I can 3D print it.

The pattern / shape I'm trying to recreate is:

[image: img1]

I can create / trace a pattern using shader nodes and curves.

[image: img2]

When I try and recreate it in geometry nodes with a displacement I run into issues.

[image: img3]

The steps I was following

1. I traced the reference image using bezier curves
2. Converted curve to mesh and filled the face
3. Added wave texture
4. Convert the displacement into mesh

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you can do this:

[image]

Basically all the node setup does is, instancing curve lines on a curve line.

Then i give a sine wave on the horizontal curve lines (the instanced lines) and rotate them a bit by their index.

I don't use boolean mesh with GN because it is often slow, sometimes buggy and sometimes it crashes Blender. So i am using the much better, more reliable and more stable raycast here. I extrude the "flat" shoe to z and i am then raycasting just to z, and if it is not hit the shoe, i delete the point. By this i can easily cut out the shoe form for my curves.